# What could cause the solid red/orange effect at the bottom of this picture?

Tags: color, effect, cmos-image-sensor

[image]I have observed an unusual effect in an RGB image where a portion of it appears solid color instead of displaying the intended colors (only once). Do you have any insights into what kind of effect this is and what might lead to such an effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a corrupt JPEG file. You should rescue any other data from the medium on which it was stored ASAP and then retire that storage; these things never get better.

Comment: If this is the reason, then I believe that during data writing onto the SD card, it got corrupted. I had thought that maybe my camera sensor had some issues...

Comment: @SwarupMaity - I'd agree with file corruption, but I've seen it happen during transfer/copying. Try copying again from the card. If it looks identical, check the camera and the card (the card is most likely and easiest to replace). If it looks different, check the cable/wi-fi/reader and the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the media that the image is stored on has some corrupt sections on it.  Probably from deleting images in the camera.  I've learned the hard way to just leave them, and delete them after import.  Also always do a low-level format of the card before using it again.